# Spark simply dont start

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Some weeks ago I was developing using jupyter and pyspark and everything was working fine.

I now returned to work on this and something happened to my environment. I absolutely can't start spark (spark-shell, pyspark or spark-submit). The log always stops in the following line:

`16/03/15 17:43:58 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator`

My environment is:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Spark 1.6.1
- Java 1.7 or 1.8 (tried both!)
- Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 6 2015, 18:08:32) [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]

The full log is here: http://pastebin.com/raw/TCb0crkA

(I don't use HADOOP, that is why HADOOP_HOME is not set)

Please, any help?!

**EDIT**

My application is in python, and the log I posted is from a standalone pyspark application started with the following command:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --py-files py-files.zip main.py`

My $SPARK_HOME is set to `/opt/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/`

Though I can't start my application, I also noted this happens to pyspark shell, and even to the scala shell.

Comment: Is this error from spark-shell or pyspark or all of them?
spark_shell or pyspark doesn't need hadoop_home unless u specify any options that tells it look for it. I have seen this error when spark-submit will have some code which need hadoop library.
What is set for your SPARK_HOME?

Comment: Sorry for missing information. Updated above.

Answer (score 0):

the log says your Hadoop_Home is not set

```
HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set
```

set HADOOP_HOME and restart your system and test again
check your environment setting , and if you are running Spark Standalone mode, you can ignore HADOOP_HOME .

Comment: As @charles-gomes said, I'm running a standalone cluster pyspark application that doesn't need HADOOP. Thanks for your help anyway!